# Displaying an image in a github readme

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to get a screenshot of my program to display on the main repository page in github. Every article online I've found was saying to simply add the markdown , but it's not working for me.

Here's the repo page: https://github.com/PainterAndHacker/LambdaCrypt

I've tried both

```
![Screenshot]\(http://i.imgur.com/ebuHuem.png)
```

and

```
![Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ebuHuem.png?raw=true)
```

But it's simply not displaying the screenshot on the repo page for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try to add md extention for you README in repo
look like right now github assume that it is simple text file

Answer (score 7):

> Display image in GitHub readme.

```
![Image](location of image in repo.type)
```

> My image place in the main branch so.

```
![Image](screenshot.jpg)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add these to GitHub. The trick is to provide the image extension, which you don't get with the default share link Imgur provides.

e.g.

```
![Imgur Image](http://i.imgur.com/zTONrOD.jpg)
```

NOT

```
![Imgur Image](http://i.imgur.com/zTONrOD)
```

You can get this under the MarkDown links in the copy menu
[image]

See embedded [example readme.md](https://github.com/twistedpair/tmux-config/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

In-case you still having trouble uploading an image to a read me file.

step 1: Add the image to a folder in your local project

step 2: push your project to GitHub

step 3: To get your image URL, open the folder where you added your image,on your GitHub repository, click the image and copy the URL.

step 4: Here is a link to a screenshot example of how to add an image.

```
   example:
```

(https://github.com/Learn-Flutter-Development/learn-flutter-development/blob/master/assets/images/gitupload.png)